# Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to SELECT from **SalesData** that created using **WITH**,
the query is

```
    with SalesData (TotalSold, OrderYear, TerritoryName)
    AS (

    SELECT SUM(soh.TotalDue) AS 'TotalSold'
        , YEAR(soh.OrderDate) AS 'OrderYear'
        , st.Name AS 'TerritoryName'
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory AS st
    ON soh.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID
    GROUP BY YEAR(soh.OrderDate)
            ,st.Name
)
SELECT TotalSold FROM SalesData
```

but SSMS gives me this error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name

I'm using Avdentureworks Database sample.

[image]

any idea why is this happening? while it's been executed well in the demo video
that I'm watching.

Comment: Try to remove the blank line before the select statement and try again.

Comment: put a semicolon before `with` like `;with cte (...) as ....`

Comment: it gives the same error. @Jens

Comment: Please post query as text in question.

Comment: @DeepakPawar It worked, thanks, but what the idea of semicolon before with ?

Comment: @beshr  from MSDN `When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon`. For more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: @beshr - But if am not wrong it generate this error `Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.`

Comment: It's better to always write semicolon after each statement. It improves readability and reduces the mistake like this. The same semicolon rule applies to `MERGE` statement.

Comment: @NoDisplayName thanks, I'll read it.

Comment: You should get used to *end*  every statement with a semicolon: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Comments of [@DeepakPawar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4149522/deepak-pawar) the solution was to

> put a semicolon before with like

```
;with cte (...) as ....
```

Also as [@Pரதீப்](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3349551/p%E0%AE%B0%E0%AE%A4%E0%AF%80%E0%AE%AA%E0%AF%8D) mentioned - referring to the following [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)  documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon

Answer (score 0):

You're missing few commands.

Place the keyword `GO` on the line after `"USE AdventureWorks"`.